# What are the possible values of “prot” parameter of “SecurityClient” header in a SIP Request?

Tags: sip

What are the possible values of `prot` parameter of `SecurityClient` header in an SIP Request?

Example:

> `Security-Client: ipsec-3gpp;prot=<?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible values of “prot” parameter are  “ah” , “no” ,”esp”

Example : prot=ah, prot=no, prot=esp